# Port forwarding from 2 routers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a server that is working fine and can be accessed within my local network. But I would like to also be able to access it from outside the network, so I tried to do port forwarding, but it didn't work. I tried troubleshooting the issue, but no luck.

This is my setup (which, unfortunately, is not simple):

I have a main router ([Huawei EG8145V5](https://e.huawei.com/ph/products/enterprise-transmission-access/access/onu/echolife-eg8145v5)) provided by my ISP and a secondary router ([TP-Link Deco M4](https://www.tp-link.com/us/deco-mesh-wifi/product-family/deco-m4)).

R1 (the main router) gives internet to R2 (the second router) via cable. 
R2 gives internet via WiFi to 3 "satelites". I'm not sure if these are also considered routers. 
One of the "satelites" gives internet via cable to a Raspberry Pi which hosts my server.

From R1's settings page, I forwarded port 1234 to R2.
From R2's settings page, I forwarded port 1234 to the RPi (apparently it detects it as if it were connected directly to R2, not to Satelite 1 which, in turn, is connected to R2).
I enabled public access on my server and tried to see if I can access it via the public IP, but I get a "connection refused" error.
I also tried scanning the open ports of the IP and it does not detect port 1234 as open.

I made all the configurations and it should just work at this point. But it doesn't. Honestly, I'm out of ideas.
I can also provide screenshots of settings if it helps.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

P.S. 
Not sure if it matters, but my server is a [Home Assistant OS](https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/raspberrypi/) instance.

Comment: Why is R2 port forwarding to the Pi?  Is R2 doing DHCP?  R1 should be handling DHCP for the entire LAN. What hardware are the *satellites*

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my ISP had blocked something one their side.
After I called them, everything worked fine.